# What problems or benefits would be associated with a "static this" keyword?

Tags: java, groovy, theory

What I am thinking of is something like the "this" keyword but at a class level i.e.

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assert Example.class == thisclass.class
    }
}
```

where "thisclass" is a keyword that returns the current class, just like "this" returns the current instance.

I can see some places where this would be useful (e.g. stopping cut&paste errors in the common logging idiom) but I can also see some potential problems (how to handle subclasses etc).

I assume that there were good reasons not to include this concept in Java but what are they? Additionally, would it be possible to do this sort of thing using Groovy meta programming?

Comment: Best way to stop copy and paste errors is not to copy and paste.

Comment: Agreed, but there are cases when copy and paste are appropriate. Declaring a logger is one of them though I suppose you could use log4e or similiar in that specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

groovy has exactly the 'this' semantics you are talking about already.  In a static context, 'this' refers to the class on which the method resides.

check out http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java and search for 'this keyword'.

Java didn't follow suit on this, obviously, probably because in the end its just a small piece of flavor that is 'groovy'.  Certainly not necessary in any way.

Comment: The differences page doesn't make it too obvious does it... but it good to know it is already available. I am looking at getting more into Groovy so any knowledge there will come in useful.

Comment: Java didn't "follow" Groovy because the Java language predates Groovy by **many** years.

Comment: @stephen, of course, but Java is still evolving was my point.

Comment: it is not the Java tradition to willy-nilly borrow features from newer languages.  The designers only extend the language when there is a strong case for doing so.

Comment: @stephen, yeah.  like i said in my answer, its not exactly the a deal breaking feature...

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a practice in C++ of typedeffing the current class to This. I tried it, didn't find any startling benefit really.